# Getting usable numbers from Nested Array Json

Tags: json, reactjs, dictionary, reduce

My data that I'm given is formulated like the following. I'm struggling to get any usable data out of it using reduce or map

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 25,
    status: 1,
    description: "No Description",
    length: 4,
    data: [
      {
        id: 43,
        comment: "Comment1",
        eventTimestamp: 1541027189000,
        intensity: 29
      },
      {
        comment: "Comment2",
        eventTimestamp: 1541027191000,
        intensity: 33
      },
      {
        id: 45,
        comment: "Comment3",
        eventTimestamp: 1541027193000,
        intensity: 30
      }
    ],
    tTypes: [
      {
        id: 3,
        label: "Johnny",
        certainty: "TEST",
        comment: "Test Purposes Only",
        icon: "bottle",
        number: 0
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I've tried flatting, I've tried iterating the JSON twice and I just seem to end up with either "NaN" or Undefined. I'd like to be able to order them in time order (using time stamp), get the mix/max/ave from the intensity values and more. I have that figured out for the length which is a level higher, but just can't seem to figure out the rest. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
export default function App() {
  let tTypesArray = data.map((a) => a.tTypes);
  let Walker = tTypesArray.reduce((a, tTypes) => tTypes.label === "Johnny" ? ++a : a, 0);

  console.log(Walker);
  console.log(tTypesArray[0].label);
  console.log([].concat(...data)
  .map(data => data.tTypes.number)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b))

  console.log([].concat(...data).reduce((a, { tTypes: { id }}) => id, 0))

  return <div className="App">ARG!</div>;
}
```

Are some of the examples I've tried.
https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-cache-ivz1y?file=/src/App.js
Is the link to the sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understood from you question is that you need to loop `data` and for each element in `data` you want to extract values and do some calculations.

First you need to loop your data input. I will use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
data.forEach(element => { ... })
```

Now that we have a loop we can access each element property and extract the information we want. For instance lets say you want to [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the comments by timestamp in ascending order:

```
const sortedComments = element.data.sort((a, b) => a.eventTimestamp - b.eventTimestamp);

console.log(sortedComments)
```

Now let's say you want the min, max, and average intensity from the comments. There are several ways to get it. Here is an algorithm for that:

```
let min = Infinity;
let max = -Infinity;
let sum = 0;

for(comment of sortedComments) {
  if(comment.intensity < min) {
    min = comment.intensity;
  }

  if(comment.intensity > max) {
    max = comment.intensity;
  }

  sum += comment.intensity;
}

const avg = sum / sortedComments.length;

console.log({min, max, avg})
```

Putting it all together:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 25,
    confirmationStatus: 1,
    description: "No Description",
    length: 4,
    data: [
      {
        id: 43,
        comment: "Comment1",
        eventTimestamp: 1541027189000,
        intensity: 29
      },
      {
        comment: "Comment2",
        eventTimestamp: 1541027191000,
        intensity: 33
      },
      {
        id: 45,
        comment: "Comment3",
        eventTimestamp: 1541027193000,
        intensity: 30
      }
    ],
    tTypes: [
      {
        id: 3,
        label: "Johnny",
        certainty: "TEST",
        comment: "Test Purposes Only",
        icon: "bottle",
        number: 0
      }
    ]
  }
];


data.forEach(element => {
  const sortedComments = element.data.sort((a, b) => a.eventTimestamp - b.eventTimestamp);

  console.log(sortedComments);
  let min = Infinity;
  let max = -Infinity;
  let sum = 0;

  for(comment of sortedComments) {
    if(comment.intensity < min) {
      min = comment.intensity;
    }

    if(comment.intensity > max) {
      max = comment.intensity;
    }

    sum += comment.intensity;
  }

  const avg = sum / sortedComments.length;

  console.log({min, max, avg});

  let walker = element.tTypes.reduce(
    (a, tType) => (tType.label === "Johnny" ? ++a : a), 0
  );

  console.log(walker)
});
```

I hope it puts you in the right direction.